# Remove empty comment tags using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-comments

I have an input xml suppose of the form

```
<A>
  <B></B>
  <!---->
  <C></C>
</A>
```

I am using XSL to transform this XML, but when I parse this XML I am getting below error message

"Error serializing file java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
Base Exception"

I have already included below command in my XSL, still getting the same error

```
<xsl:template match="comment()"/>
```

Please help!

TIA :)

Comment: It looks like a bug in the XML parser or XSLT processor. Seeing a stack trace would help; and we need to know which XML parser and XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the code you're using to parse/transform the XML?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  <xsl:template match="comment()[.='']"/>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <!---->
  <!--above comment line should be deleted-->
  <foo>
    <!--fooo data-->
    <foobar/>
  </foo>
</root>
```

Input XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="comment()[.='']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <!--above comment line should be deleted-->
  <foo>
    <!--fooo data-->
    <foobar />
  </foo>
</root>
```

Comment: thank you @infantPro'Arvind'. But I am still getting the same exception: "Error serializing file java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 Base Exception"

Comment: @Vix, As per my knowledge this has nothing to do with XSLT method of removing comment! The reason I added my answer is that, your sample XSLT removes all the comments! Where as adding `<xsl:template match="comment()[.='']"/>` removes only those comment tags which don't have any data!